# Magento 2 Show Banners on Non CMS Page

Tags: magento2

I would like to show some of the colorful banner images for customers login/sign in pages. So, I have to create cms static block section to upload the banners and the same will be shown in front end. I tried to use `content.top` or `columns.top` for calling cms static block but it's not show anything in the front end.

```
<referenceContainer name="content.top">
    <container name="login.banner" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="banner-view">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="login-info">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">login-banner</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Any help much appreciation.

**Edit** I would like to show this banner as like how category page banners are works. The banner should be shown before the page title section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my work around which is worked as expected. Moved page main title to `columns.top` section and called CMS Static block section inside of `columns.top` section.

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="page-title" after="banner.view.container"/>

<referenceContainer name="columns.top" after="-">
    <container name="banner.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="cms-banner-view" after="-">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="banner-view" template="Magento_Theme::cms-banner.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="cms-banner-section">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">login-banner</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </block>
    </container>

    <container name="page-title" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-title" after="-">
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" after="columns.top">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Log In / Sign Up</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Finally, Create phtml file to call the declared block name.

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('cms-banner-section'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this php file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('login-banner')->toHtml();?>
```

For Xml 
block_id == your block id

```
 <referenceContainer name="content.top">
<container name="login.banner" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="banner-view">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="login-banner">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">login-banner</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</container>
```

Comment: I agree with you. But I would like to handle this one through layout XML instead of directly calling.